# What is the prefered way to converting a string to an int, security-wise?

Tags: php, performance, security, type-conversion

There are multiple ways of converting a string to an integer.

```
$someString = substr($input, strripos($input, "_") + 1);
$i = $someString + 0;
$i = (int) $someString;
$i = intval($someString);
```

`$someString` comes from use input, so that might have to be taken into consideration. Which option is “better” or has the most negative side-effects? (i.e. performance-wise, security-wise)

`$input` can look something like `1_abcd_1` or `1_abcd_2`. That is quite fixed — except for the *abcd* which is made up in this example. This input comes from radio buttons, but a user can always alter their data if they want to. Thus, I have to account for malicious data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input is being cast to a number, there’s no security issues. Performance differences are negligible. However, the first one may not produce an integer in certain cases.

For example, let `$input = '19.99';`.

```
$i = $someString + 0;    // $i = 19.99
```

The other two cases are equivalent, but `$i = (int) $someString;` averages approximately 56% faster than `$i = intval($someString);`. Since both execute in a matter of milliseconds, performance differences are generally negligible unless they occur in a sizable loop.

```
$i = (int) $someString;      // $i = 9
$i = intval($someString);    // $i = 9
```

On the matter of security: if you expect `$input` to always be in a specific form (*e.g.* **#_xxxx_#**), then you should verify that it *is* in that format. Expanding on Jack’s comment — if you’re using PHP >= 5.2.0, you can check the format of the input using a regular expression.

```
<?php
$input = '1_abcd_1';

// Set the desired format
$filter_options = array(
    'options' => array(
        // choose a regular expression that matches your format
        'regexp' => '/^[\d]_[a-z]{4}_[\d]$/'
    )
);

$format = filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, $filter_options);
if ($format !== false) {
    // process input
    $someString = substr($format, strripos($format, "_") + 1);
    $i = (int) $someString;
    echo '$i = ', $i;
} else {
    // Handle invalid format
    echo 'Malformed data. Potentially malicious';
}
?>
```

This will completely reject things like:

```
0xfe
bob
j_xtyz_5
1_wxyz_22
21_abcd_1
1_Abcd_2
```

Naturally, you would adjust the regular expression to your needs.

See also:

- [Dev Shed Tutorials: Checking regular expressions with the filter extension - PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Working-with-Regular-Expressions-with-Filters-in-PHP-5/2/)
- [PHP Manual: filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

If you’re not using PHP >= 5.2.0, you can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
<?php
$input = '1_abcd_2';

$valid = preg_match('/^[\d]_[a-z]{4}_[\d]$/', $input);
if ($valid) {
    // process input
    $someString = substr($input, strripos($input, "_") + 1);
    $i = (int) $someString;
    echo '$i = ', $i;
} else {
    // Handle invalid format
    echo 'Malformed data. Potentially malicious';
}
?>
```

Validating the format of the input let’s you know immediately if the data has been tampered with. Then you can act accordingly.

Comment: Interesting :-). Will combine yours with Rajan Rawal suggestion of using `is_numeric()`

Comment: @DaanTimmer no, `is_numeric('0xfe') == true` which is probably not what you want; if you want to test integers you can use `filter_var`

Comment: I updated my answer to expand on security. Thanks for bringing up filter_var @Jack

Answer (score 3):

I prefer type casting, `$i = (int) $someString;` which is clear.

Comment: Same, will accept Herbert's answer for being a bit more thorough. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be sure about $someString is numeric only you can use

```
if(is_numeric($someString)){
   // proceed your code if $someString is numeric
}else{
   // proceed your code if $someString is not numeric
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know about the explode version. Might indeed be a good idea to do a is_numeric check. And no database operations are performed. Even if I did I would use PDO and that does not require mysql_real_escape. Which also doesn't stop SQL injections btw.

Comment: sorry, i was not knowing that you are using PDO. I just mentioned as you had mentioned security-wise in your question. Thank you.

Comment: I just made a performance test between the two ways of extracting the numerical value (explode vs substr) and the explode is ~5% slower. I ran each 'function' 100000 times. and that in a loop of 10times. The values were between 4% and 7% slower. Still thanks for taking the time. And I do like the suggestion of using is_numeric first.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware about such time consumption. From next time i will use it. and hence updating answer.

Comment: Remember that `is_numeric()` is just a test and, unlike the explicit `(int)` cast or `intval()`, leaves you with a variable that is still of datatype string. I.e. this will not "convert to an int" as the question asks.

Comment: `is_numeric('0xef') == true`, but `(int)'0xef' == 0` :)